# Is there any way to remove certain pinned Apps / links from Windows 11 taskbar / start menu with PowerShell?

Tags: windows, powershell, taskbar, start-menu, windows-11

I need to remove certain pinned Apps (Microsoft Edge, Microsoft Store, Prime Video etc.) from the Windows 11 taskbar and start menu with powershell.

I have done lots of Googling but I couldn't find a working solution. All the Windows 10 solutions do not work.

Comment: My work does this programmatically inside MDT so it DOES work. Please indicate specific things you've tried that have failed, maybe you're missing a step

Comment: Apologize my work does it in Win10, I overlooked you mentioned Win11. I'm a little surprised if it doesn't work, but totally possible. Still would be good to hear WHAT you have tried so people don't suggest that or can point out if you missed or had an incorrect step/process. Haven't read this yet, maybe it'll help?
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/customize/desktop/customize-the-windows-11-start-menu or https://medium.com/@MrNick4B/deploy-a-customized-windows-11-start-menu-8832d90b25b1

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Transcribing steps from an online article](https://medium.com/@MrNick4B/deploy-a-customized-windows-11-start-menu-8832d90b25b1), DO let us know if it works:

1. Pin apps to the Start Menu the way you like it
2. Copy file `%LocalAppData%\Packages\Microsoft.Windows.StartMenuExperienceHost_cw5n1h2txyewy\LocalState\start.bin`
3. Paste/move file to Default users directory `%SystemDrive%\Users\Default\AppData\Local\Packages\Microsoft.Windows.StartMenuExperienceHost_cw5n1h2txyewy\LocalState\`. In the past that meant it'd only apply to NEW user profiles so if you have existing profiles you either have to delete them so they get recreate on user login OR copy this file to their profile & have them sign out & back in (or restart)

I'm curious if it'll work in the long term since it APPEARS this isn't an approved MS way of doing things possibly indicating it was an intentional design choice by Microsoft and/or a glaring oversight given this functionality existed & was changed since Win10. As [@John's answer](https://superuser.com/a/1689319/160219) indicated Microsoft has indicated in the past ([notably with file associations](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/ask-the-performance-team/how-to-configure-file-associations-for-it-pros/ba-p/1313151)) their intentional design making it so ONLY users can tweak things that previously programmers/admins can tweak for users.

Comment: Sorry for the necro, just wanted to post that I just tried this on my Windows 11 machine and it did not work. Neither replacing existing users' start.bin or placing in \Users\Default\ (which did not have a Packages folder and had to be manually created) worked. I even went as far as copying the whole Microsoft.Windows.StartMenuExperienceHost_cw5n1h2txyewy folder but that also did nothing. Logging in as a new AD or local user on the machine did not pull the config from \Users\Default.

Comment: I just found this and tested working in removing TikTok/Disney+/etc for all users. 

"Set-ItemProperty -path HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\CloudContent -name DisableCloudOptimizedContent -Value 1 -Force" and "Set-ItemProperty -path HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\CloudContent -name DisableConsumerAccountStateContent -Value 1 -Force"

Answer (score 2):

When I saw TikTok on a fresh Windows 11 Pro install I almost lost my head! I expect this from Dell or MS HOME editions but not fresh MS pro.

And yes TikTok is on all Windows 11 Pro fresh installs hidden under `c:\program files\WindowsApp` with a bunch of other BS.

First TakeOwn of the WindowsApp folder.

```
cd program files
takeown /F WindowsApps /A /R /D Y   (Gives all admins control of this folder)

cd WindowsApps
attrib BytedancePte.Ltd.TikTok_1.0.5.0_neutral__6yccndn6064se -r -s -h
takeown /f BytedancePte.Ltd.TikTok_1.0.5.0_neutral__6yccndn6064se /grant "%USERDOMAIN%\%USERNAME%":(F) /t
rmdir BytedancePte.Ltd.TikTok_1.0.5.0_neutral__6yccndn6064se /q /s
```

and then I repeat..

```
icacls SpotifyAB.SpotifyMusic_1.200.1165.0_x86__zpdnekdrzrea0  /grant "%USERDOMAIN%\%USERNAME%":(F) /t
attrib SpotifyAB.SpotifyMusic_1.200.1165.0_x86__zpdnekdrzrea0 -r -h -s
rmdir SpotifyAB.SpotifyMusic_1.200.1165.0_x86__zpdnekdrzrea0 /q /s
```

Also had to disable the behavioral scanner on my AV before doing any of this..

Note there are two bytedance folders.

We also got rid of Disney, ESPN &  Adobe Express

There is probably a reg key that puts these on the start menu - looking for that now

`%USERDOMAIN%\%USERNAME%` is code for "me"

Answer (score 1):

For testing the PowerShell example below, I have pinned the
Registry Editor to the taskbar.

In the script below, a function is defined named `UnPin-App`
that unpins a pinned app on the taskbar whose name is passed
as parameter.
Following that, the function is called to unpin the Registry Editor.
Finally, `explorer.exe` is restarted.

For unpinning your apps, add calls to `UnPin-App`.

```
function UnPin-App { param(
        [string]$appname
    )
    try {
        ((New-Object -Com Shell.Application).NameSpace('shell:::{4234d49b-0245-4df3-b780-3893943456e1}').Items() | ?{$_.Name -eq $appname}).Verbs() | ?{$_.Name.replace('&','') -match 'Unpin from taskbar'} | %{$_.DoIt()}
        return "App '$appname' unpinned from Taskbar"
    } catch {
        Write-Error "Error Unpinning App! (App-Name correct?)"
    }
}

UnPin-App "Registry Editor"

stop-process -name explorer –force
```

Note: This was tested on Windows 10.

Comment: This does not work in Windows 11, just FYI. I have not yet found a solution.

Answer (score 1):

Turned out this works much better. I wasn't running Powershell as admin which is why I thought it didn't work.

```
Get-AppxPackage *tiktok* | Remove-AppxPackage
Get-AppxPackage *Disney* | Remove-AppxPackage
```

I found these items to be unpinned as well.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I solved with this .BAT:

```
DEL /F /S /Q /A "%AppData%\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Quick Launch\User Pinned\TaskBar\skype empresarial.lnk"

REG DELETE HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Taskband\ /v FavoritesRemovedChanges /f

taskkill /f /im explorer.exe

start explorer.exe
```